# How to integrate flask and npm together

Tags: html, web, flask, npm, npm-install

I have a flask app that starts with

> python3 app.py

in localhost:5000

I also found another nodejs app that starts with

> npm run start

in localhost:3000

I want to integrate the npm in my flask app. After statrting the flask app, if I press a html button in flask app, I want the npm app to run. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I really would not recommend this!

There are other tools to make sure your services are running, e.g. `systemd` or `supervisor`.

If you really insist to do it with `Flask` - and really please don't do it...

```
import os
os.system("npm run start")
```

Have I already told you not to do this? :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I am doing this for a immidiate project. So there is not much time to do work around and also learning.
Btw, for this 
os.system("npm run start")
to work, do I need all the project files in the same directory? What to do if the flask and the npm are different directory?

Comment: Also, what should be my workaround if I want to integrate the npm with flask?

Comment: I really advice you not to do this. If you need both services running, and you have no time to read about supervisor nor systemd, please start both apps manually - this is absolute ok to get the project going - then sit down half a day, and read about proper service starting.